# Return nothing in VB6

Tags: function, textbox, vb6

Quite simply i need to figure out how to rewrite the following code for VB6 so that my application allows nothing to be passed into a textbox.text value

```
Function GetDbValue(ByVal tb)
 If tb.Text = "" Then
Return Nothing
Else
 Return tb.Text
End If
  End Function
```

Im getting a syntax error for "return nothing"

EDIT:

Stored proc

```
 Set prm = cmdDlrID.CreateParameter("@ContractNumberField", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50, GetDbValue(txtContNum))
 cmdDlrID.Parameters.Append prm
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VB6 there are at least four different types of nothing:

- `Nothing`, a null pointer as an object
- `vbNullString`, a null pointer as a string
- `Empty`, an uninitialized variant
- `Null`, a null value passed to / from a database

If you're passing the function into an ADO parameter, you need `Null`, not `Nothing`:

```
Function GetDbValue(ByVal tb)
    If tb.Text = "" Then
        GetDbValue = Null
    Else
        GetDbValue = tb.Text
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it like this (untested):

```
Function GetDbValue(ByVal tb)
 If tb.Text = "" Then
  Set GetDbValue = Nothing
 Else
  GetDbValue = tb.Text
 End If
End Function
```

IIRC, you don't use the `Return` keyword to return a function value in VB6/VBA, you assign the return value to the function's name.

Comment: +1 the [`Return`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243378(v=vs.60).aspx) statement in VB6 is for use with [`Gosub`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243378(v=vs.60).aspx), not to exit a function. [See VB6 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa243378(v=vs.60).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly to return a value in VB6, you set the function equal to that value

So you code would look something like this.

```
Function GetDbValue(ByVal tb as TextBox) as String
 If tb.Text = "" Then
    GetDbValue =  Nothing
 Else
    GetDbValue = tb.Text
 End If
End Function
```

A short tutorial on Sub routines and Functions can be found [here](http://www.vb6.us/tutorials/understanding-subroutines-and-functions-vb)

Comment: ok it seems as if this works but when i try to store this nothing into the database, i get "application uses a value of the wrong type for the current operation" error Ill edit with what my proc looks like

Comment: Zingo, I believe that is because VB6 Nothing is a different type than DBNull.Value. Just make the substitution in the code above.

Comment: So change "Nothing" to DBNULL.Value?